# SQL loop to pull and use data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create a loop which pulls the SET ID #, then creates a item_loot_template entry with all items that have the SET ID # as their # in the item_template column named `itemset`. then create a item_template entry with `name` column being the "SET NAME" + ' Set' and do this for every SET ID listed below.

I am really new to SQL so I really have no clue how I would go about doing this but I am pretty sure the best way to go about it would be to set the itemset data to an array and to make a loop that pulls from the array and the other data needed to input into the querys.

I have also included some screen shots in order to try and make this more understandable :S

item_loot_template query to use:

```
INSERT INTO `item_loot_template` (`Entry`, `Item`, `Reference`, `Chance`, `QuestRequired`, `LootMode`, `GroupId`, `MinCount`, `MaxCount`, `Comment`) VALUES (@BASEENTRY, @ITEMENTRYID, 0, 100, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL);
```

item_template query needed to use:

```
INSERT INTO `item_template` (`entry`, `class`, `subclass`, `SoundOverrideSubclass`, `name`, `displayid`, `Quality`, `Flags`, `FlagsExtra`, `BuyCount`, `BuyPrice`, `SellPrice`, `InventoryType`, `AllowableClass`, `AllowableRace`, `ItemLevel`, `RequiredLevel`, `RequiredSkill`, `RequiredSkillRank`, `requiredspell`, `requiredhonorrank`, `RequiredCityRank`, `RequiredReputationFaction`, `RequiredReputationRank`, `maxcount`, `stackable`, `ContainerSlots`, `StatsCount`, `stat_type1`, `stat_value1`, `stat_type2`, `stat_value2`, `stat_type3`, `stat_value3`, `stat_type4`, `stat_value4`, `stat_type5`, `stat_value5`, `stat_type6`, `stat_value6`, `stat_type7`, `stat_value7`, `stat_type8`, `stat_value8`, `stat_type9`, `stat_value9`, `stat_type10`, `stat_value10`, `ScalingStatDistribution`, `ScalingStatValue`, `dmg_min1`, `dmg_max1`, `dmg_type1`, `dmg_min2`, `dmg_max2`, `dmg_type2`, `armor`, `holy_res`, `fire_res`, `nature_res`, `frost_res`, `shadow_res`, `arcane_res`, `delay`, `ammo_type`, `RangedModRange`, `spellid_1`, `spelltrigger_1`, `spellcharges_1`, `spellppmRate_1`, `spellcooldown_1`, `spellcategory_1`, `spellcategorycooldown_1`, `spellid_2`, `spelltrigger_2`, `spellcharges_2`, `spellppmRate_2`, `spellcooldown_2`, `spellcategory_2`, `spellcategorycooldown_2`, `spellid_3`, `spelltrigger_3`, `spellcharges_3`, `spellppmRate_3`, `spellcooldown_3`, `spellcategory_3`, `spellcategorycooldown_3`, `spellid_4`, `spelltrigger_4`, `spellcharges_4`, `spellppmRate_4`, `spellcooldown_4`, `spellcategory_4`, `spellcategorycooldown_4`, `spellid_5`, `spelltrigger_5`, `spellcharges_5`, `spellppmRate_5`, `spellcooldown_5`, `spellcategory_5`, `spellcategorycooldown_5`, `bonding`, `description`, `PageText`, `LanguageID`, `PageMaterial`, `startquest`, `lockid`, `Material`, `sheath`, `RandomProperty`, `RandomSuffix`, `block`, `itemset`, `MaxDurability`, `area`, `Map`, `BagFamily`, `TotemCategory`, `socketColor_1`, `socketContent_1`, `socketColor_2`, `socketContent_2`, `socketColor_3`, `socketContent_3`, `socketBonus`, `GemProperties`, `RequiredDisenchantSkill`, `ArmorDamageModifier`, `duration`, `ItemLimitCategory`, `HolidayId`, `ScriptName`, `DisenchantID`, `FoodType`, `minMoneyLoot`, `maxMoneyLoot`, `flagsCustom`, `VerifiedBuild`) VALUES 
(@ENTRYID, 15, 0, -1, @setname + ' Set', 9632, 6, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 'Contains the ' + @SETNAME +'SET', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12340);
```

itemset ids with names:

```
[1] = "The Gladiator",
[41] = "Dal'Rend's Arms",
[65] = "Spider's Kiss",
[81] = "The Postmaster",
[121] = "Cadaverous Garb",
[122] = "Necropile Raiment",
[123] = "Bloodmail Regalia",
[124] = "Deathbone Guardian",
[141] = "Volcanic Armor",
[142] = "Stormshroud Armor",
[143] = "Devilsaur Armor",
[144] = "Ironfeather Armor",
[161] = "Defias Leather",
[162] = "Embrace of the Viper",
[163] = "Chain of the Scarlet Crusade",
[181] = "Magister's Regalia",
[182] = "Vestments of the Devout",
[183] = "Dreadmist Raiment",
[184] = "Shadowcraft Armor",
[185] = "Wildheart Raiment",
[186] = "Beaststalker Armor",
[187] = "The Elements",
[188] = "Lightforge Armor",
[189] = "Battlegear of Valor",
[201] = "Arcanist Regalia",
[202] = "Vestments of Prophecy",
[203] = "Felheart Raiment",
[204] = "Nightslayer Armor",
[205] = "Cenarion Raiment",
[206] = "Giantstalker Armor",
[207] = "The Earthfury",
[208] = "Lawbringer Armor",
[209] = "Battlegear of Might",
[210] = "Netherwind Regalia",
[211] = "Vestments of Transcendence",
[212] = "Nemesis Raiment",
[213] = "Bloodfang Armor",
[214] = "Stormrage Raiment",
[215] = "Dragonstalker Armor",
[216] = "The Ten Storms",
[217] = "Judgement Armor",
[218] = "Battlegear of Wrath",
[221] = "Garb of Thero-shan",
[241] = "Shard of the Gods",
[261] = "Spirit of Eskhandar",
[281] = "Champion's Battlegear",
[282] = "Lieutenant Commander's Battlegear",
[301] = "Champion's Earthshaker",
[321] = "Imperial Plate",
[341] = "Champion's Regalia",
[342] = "Champion's Raiment",
[343] = "Lieutenant Commander's Regalia",
[344] = "Lieutenant Commander's Raiment",
[345] = "Champion's Threads",
[346] = "Lieutenant Commander's Threads",
[347] = "Champion's Vestments",
[348] = "Lieutenant Commander's Vestments",
[361] = "Champion's Pursuit",
[362] = "Lieutenant Commander's Pursuit",
[381] = "Lieutenant Commander's Sanctuary",
[382] = "Champion's Sanctuary",
[383] = "Warlord's Battlegear",
[384] = "Field Marshal's Battlegear",
[386] = "Warlord's Earthshaker",
[387] = "Warlord's Regalia",
[388] = "Field Marshal's Regalia",
[389] = "Field Marshal's Raiment",
[390] = "Warlord's Raiment",
[391] = "Warlord's Threads",
[392] = "Field Marshal's Threads",
[393] = "Warlord's Vestments",
[394] = "Field Marshal's Vestments",
[395] = "Field Marshal's Pursuit",
[396] = "Warlord's Pursuit",
[397] = "Field Marshal's Sanctuary",
[398] = "Warlord's Sanctuary",
[401] = "Lieutenant Commander's Aegis",
[402] = "Field Marshal's Aegis",
[421] = "Bloodvine Garb",
[441] = "Primal Batskin",
[442] = "Blood Tiger Harness",
[443] = "Bloodsoul Embrace",
[444] = "The Darksoul",
[461] = "The Twin Blades of Hakkari",
[462] = "Zanzil's Concentration",
[463] = "Primal Blessing",
[464] = "Overlord's Resolution",
[465] = "Prayer of the Primal",
[466] = "Major Mojo Infusion",
[467] = "The Highlander's Resolution",
[468] = "The Highlander's Resolve",
[469] = "The Highlander's Determination",
[470] = "The Highlander's Fortitude",
[471] = "The Highlander's Purpose",
[472] = "The Highlander's Will",
[473] = "The Highlander's Intent",
[474] = "Vindicator's Battlegear",
[475] = "Freethinker's Armor",
[476] = "Augur's Regalia",
[477] = "Predator's Armor",
[478] = "Madcap's Outfit",
[479] = "Haruspex's Garb",
[480] = "Confessor's Raiment",
[481] = "Demoniac's Threads",
[482] = "Illusionist's Attire",
[483] = "The Defiler's Determination",
[484] = "The Defiler's Fortitude",
[485] = "The Defiler's Intent",
[486] = "The Defiler's Purpose",
[487] = "The Defiler's Resolution",
[488] = "The Defiler's Will",
[489] = "Black Dragon Mail",
[490] = "Green Dragon Mail",
[491] = "Blue Dragon Mail",
[492] = "Twilight Trappings",
[493] = "Genesis Raiment",
[494] = "Symbols of Unending Life",
[495] = "Battlegear of Unyielding Strength",
[496] = "Conqueror's Battlegear",
[497] = "Deathdealer's Embrace",
[498] = "Emblems of Veiled Shadows",
[499] = "Doomcaller's Attire",
[500] = "Implements of Unspoken Names",
[501] = "Stormcaller's Garb",
[502] = "Gift of the Gathering Storm",
[503] = "Enigma Vestments",
[504] = "Trappings of Vaulted Secrets",
[505] = "Avenger's Battlegear",
[506] = "Battlegear of Eternal Justice",
[507] = "Garments of the Oracle",
[508] = "Finery of Infinite Wisdom",
[509] = "Striker's Garb",
[510] = "Trappings of the Unseen Path",
[511] = "Battlegear of Heroism",
[512] = "Darkmantle Armor",
[513] = "Feralheart Raiment",
[514] = "Vestments of the Virtuous",
[515] = "Beastmaster Armor",
[516] = "Soulforge Armor",
[517] = "Sorcerer's Regalia",
[518] = "Deathmist Raiment",
[519] = "The Five Thunders",
[520] = "Ironweave Battlesuit",
[521] = "Dreamwalker Raiment",
[522] = "Champion's Guard",
[523] = "Dreadnaught's Battlegear",
[524] = "Bonescythe Armor",
[525] = "Vestments of Faith",
[526] = "Frostfire Regalia",
[527] = "The Earthshatterer",
[528] = "Redemption Armor",
[529] = "Plagueheart Raiment",
[530] = "Cryptstalker Armor",
[533] = "Battlegear of Undead Slaying",
[534] = "Undead Slayer's Armor",
[535] = "Garb of the Undead Slayer",
[536] = "Regalia of Undead Cleansing",
[537] = "Champion's Battlearmor",
[538] = "Champion's Stormcaller",
[539] = "Champion's Refuge",
[540] = "Champion's Investiture",
[541] = "Champion's Dreadgear",
[542] = "Champion's Arcanum",
[543] = "Champion's Pursuance",
[544] = "Lieutenant Commander's Redoubt",
[545] = "Lieutenant Commander's Battlearmor",
[546] = "Lieutenant Commander's Arcanum",
[547] = "Lieutenant Commander's Dreadgear",
[548] = "Lieutenant Commander's Guard",
[549] = "Lieutenant Commander's Investiture",
[550] = "Lieutenant Commander's Pursuance",
[551] = "Lieutenant Commander's Refuge",
[552] = "Wrath of Spellfire",
[553] = "Shadow's Embrace",
[554] = "Primal Mooncloth",
[555] = "Netherweave Vestments",
[556] = "Imbued Netherweave",
[557] = "Soulcloth Embrace",
[558] = "Arcanoweave Vestments",
[559] = "Spellstrike Infusion",
[560] = "Fel Iron Plate",
[561] = "Fel Iron Chain",
[562] = "Adamantite Battlegear",
[563] = "Enchanted Adamantite Armor",
[564] = "Flame Guard",
[565] = "Khorium Ward",
[566] = "Burning Rage",
[567] = "Gladiator's Battlegear",
[568] = "Gladiator's Dreadgear",
[569] = "Faith in Felsteel",
[570] = "The Unyielding",
[571] = "Whitemend Wisdom",
[572] = "Battlecast Garb",
[573] = "Fel Skin",
[574] = "Strength of the Clefthoof",
[575] = "Felstalker Armor",
[576] = "Fury of the Nether",
[577] = "Gladiator's Vestments",
[578] = "Gladiator's Earthshaker",
[579] = "Gladiator's Regalia",
[580] = "Gladiator's Thunderfist",
[581] = "Gladiator's Raiment",
[582] = "Gladiator's Aegis",
[583] = "Gladiator's Vindication",
[584] = "Gladiator's Sanctuary",
[585] = "Gladiator's Wildhide",
[586] = "Gladiator's Pursuit",
[587] = "High Warlord's Aegis",
[588] = "High Warlord's Battlegear",
[589] = "Grand Marshal's Aegis",
[590] = "Grand Marshal's Battlegear",
[591] = "Grand Marshal's Dreadgear",
[592] = "High Warlord's Dreadgear",
[593] = "Grand Marshal's Earthshaker",
[594] = "High Warlord's Earthshaker",
[595] = "Grand Marshal's Pursuit",
[596] = "High Warlord's Pursuit",
[597] = "Grand Marshal's Raiment",
[598] = "High Warlord's Raiment",
[599] = "Grand Marshal's Regalia",
[600] = "High Warlord's Regalia",
[601] = "Grand Marshal's Sanctuary",
[602] = "High Warlord's Sanctuary",
[603] = "Grand Marshal's Thunderfist",
[604] = "High Warlord's Thunderfist",
[605] = "Grand Marshal's Vestments",
[606] = "High Warlord's Vestments",
[607] = "Grand Marshal's Vindication",
[608] = "High Warlord's Vindication",
[609] = "Grand Marshal's Wildhide",
[610] = "High Warlord's Wildhide",
[611] = "Felscale Armor",
[612] = "Scaled Draenic Armor",
[613] = "Thick Draenic Armor",
[614] = "Wild Draenish Armor",
[615] = "Gladiator's Felshroud",
[616] = "Netherscale Armor",
[617] = "Netherstrike Armor",
[618] = "Windhawk Armor",
[619] = "Primal Intent",
[620] = "Assassination Armor",
[621] = "Netherblade",
[622] = "Deathmantle",
[623] = "Righteous Armor",
[624] = "Justicar Raiment",
[625] = "Justicar Armor",
[626] = "Justicar Battlegear",
[627] = "Crystalforge Raiment",
[628] = "Crystalforge Armor",
[629] = "Crystalforge Battlegear",
[630] = "Tidefury Raiment",
[631] = "Cyclone Raiment",
[632] = "Cyclone Regalia",
[633] = "Cyclone Harness",
[634] = "Cataclysm Raiment",
[635] = "Cataclysm Regalia",
[636] = "Cataclysm Harness",
[637] = "Moonglade Raiment",
[638] = "Malorne Raiment",
[639] = "Malorne Regalia",
[640] = "Malorne Harness",
[641] = "Nordrassil Harness",
[642] = "Nordrassil Raiment",
[643] = "Nordrassil Regalia",
[644] = "Oblivion Raiment",
[645] = "Voidheart Raiment",
[646] = "Corruptor Raiment",
[647] = "Incanter's Regalia",
[648] = "Aldor Regalia",
[649] = "Tirisfal Regalia",
[650] = "Beast Lord Armor",
[651] = "Demon Stalker Armor",
[652] = "Rift Stalker Armor",
[653] = "Bold Armor",
[654] = "Warbringer Armor",
[655] = "Warbringer Battlegear",
[656] = "Destroyer Armor",
[657] = "Destroyer Battlegear",
[658] = "Mana-Etched Regalia",
[659] = "Wastewalker Armor",
[660] = "Desolation Battlegear",
[661] = "Doomplate Battlegear",
[662] = "Hallowed Raiment",
[663] = "Incarnate Raiment",
[664] = "Incarnate Regalia",
[665] = "Avatar Raiment",
[666] = "Avatar Regalia",
[667] = "The Twin Stars",
[668] = "Slayer's Armor",
[669] = "Gronnstalker's Armor",
[670] = "Malefic Raiment",
[671] = "Tempest Regalia",
[672] = "Onslaught Battlegear",
[673] = "Onslaught Armor",
[674] = "Absolution Regalia",
[675] = "Vestments of Absolution",
[676] = "Thunderheart Harness",
[677] = "Thunderheart Regalia",
[678] = "Thunderheart Raiment",
[679] = "Lightbringer Armor",
[680] = "Lightbringer Battlegear",
[681] = "Lightbringer Raiment",
[682] = "Skyshatter Harness",
[683] = "Skyshatter Raiment",
[684] = "Skyshatter Regalia",
[685] = "Gladiator's Refuge",
[686] = "Gladiator's Wartide",
[687] = "Gladiator's Investiture",
[688] = "Grand Marshal's Refuge",
[689] = "High Warlord's Refuge",
[690] = "Gladiator's Redemption",
[691] = "Grand Marshal's Investiture",
[692] = "High Warlord's Investiture",
[693] = "Grand Marshal's Redemption",
[694] = "High Warlord's Redemption",
[695] = "Grand Marshal's Wartide",
[696] = "High Warlord's Wartide",
[697] = "Champion's Redoubt",
[698] = "Warlord's Aegis",
[699] = "The Twin Blades of Azzinoth",
[700] = "Merciless Gladiator's Aegis",
[701] = "Merciless Gladiator's Battlegear",
[702] = "Merciless Gladiator's Dreadgear",
[703] = "Merciless Gladiator's Earthshaker",
[704] = "Merciless Gladiator's Felshroud",
[705] = "Merciless Gladiator's Investiture",
[706] = "Merciless Gladiator's Pursuit",
[707] = "Merciless Gladiator's Raiment",
[708] = "Merciless Gladiator's Redemption",
[709] = "Merciless Gladiator's Refuge",
[710] = "Merciless Gladiator's Regalia",
[711] = "Merciless Gladiator's Sanctuary",
[712] = "Merciless Gladiator's Thunderfist",
[713] = "Merciless Gladiator's Vestments",
[714] = "Merciless Gladiator's Vindication",
[715] = "Merciless Gladiator's Wartide",
[716] = "Merciless Gladiator's Wildhide",
[717] = "Field Marshal's Earthshaker",
[718] = "Lieutenant Commander's Earthshaker",
[719] = "The Fists of Fury",
[720] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Refuge",
[721] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Sanctuary",
[722] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Wildhide",
[723] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Pursuit",
[724] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Regalia",
[725] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Redemption",
[726] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Vindication",
[727] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Aegis",
[728] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Investiture",
[729] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Raiment",
[730] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Vestments",
[731] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Wartide",
[732] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Earthshaker",
[733] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Thunderfist",
[734] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Dreadgear",
[735] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Felshroud",
[736] = "Vengeful Gladiator's Battlegear",
[737] = "Latro's Flurry",
[738] = "Dreadweave Battlegear",
[739] = "Mooncloth Battlegear",
[740] = "Satin Battlegear",
[741] = "Evoker's Silk Battlegear",
[742] = "Dragonhide Battlegear",
[743] = "Wyrmhide Battlegear",
[744] = "Kodohide Battlegear",
[745] = "Opportunist's Battlegear",
[746] = "Seer's Mail Battlegear",
[747] = "Seer's Ringmail Battlegear",
[748] = "Seer's Linked Battlegear",
[749] = "Stalker's Chain Battlegear",
[750] = "Savage Plate Battlegear",
[751] = "Crusader's Ornamented Battlegear",
[752] = "Crusader's Scaled Battlegear",
[754] = "Borean Embrace",
[755] = "Nerubian Hive",
[756] = "Frostscale Binding",
[757] = "Iceborne Embrace",
[759] = "Raine's Revenge",
[760] = "Gladiator's Dreadplate",
[761] = "Winter Garb",
[762] = "Brewfest Garb",
[763] = "Frostwoven Power",
[764] = "Duskweaver",
[765] = "Gladiator's Battlegear",
[766] = "Gladiator's Vindication",
[767] = "Gladiator's Redemption",
[768] = "Gladiator's Desecration",
[769] = "Gladiator's Thunderfist",
[770] = "Gladiator's Earthshaker",
[771] = "Gladiator's Wartide",
[772] = "Gladiator's Pursuit",
[773] = "Gladiator's Refuge",
[774] = "Gladiator's Wildhide",
[775] = "Gladiator's Sanctuary",
[776] = "Gladiator's Vestments",
[777] = "Gladiator's Investiture",
[778] = "Gladiator's Raiment",
[779] = "Gladiator's Regalia",
[780] = "Gladiator's Felshroud",
[781] = "Blessed Regalia of Undead Cleansing",
[782] = "Undead Slayer's Blessed Armor",
[783] = "Blessed Garb of the Undead Slayer",
[784] = "Blessed Battlegear of Undead Slaying",
[785] = "Midsummer Reveler",
[787] = "Dreadnaught Plate",
[788] = "Dreadnaught Battlegear",
[789] = "Redemption Battlegear",
[790] = "Redemption Regalia",
[791] = "Redemption Plate",
[792] = "Scourgeborne Battlegear",
[793] = "Scourgeborne Plate",
[794] = "Cryptstalker Battlegear",
[795] = "Earthshatter Battlegear",
[796] = "Earthshatter Garb",
[797] = "Earthshatter Regalia",
[798] = "Dreamwalker Battlegear",
[799] = "Dreamwalker Regalia",
[800] = "Dreamwalker Garb",
[801] = "Bonescythe Battlegear",
[802] = "Plagueheart Garb",
[803] = "Frostfire Garb",
[804] = "Regalia of Faith",
[805] = "Garb of Faith",
[812] = "Spring Tuxedo",
[813] = "Eviscerator's Battlegear",
[814] = "Ornate Saronite Battlegear",
[815] = "Overcaster Battlegear",
[816] = "Savage Saronite Battlegear",
[817] = "Stormhide Battlegear",
[818] = "Swiftarrow Battlegear",
[819] = "Frostsavage Battlegear",
[820] = "Aegis Battlegear",
[821] = "Aegis Plate",
[822] = "Aegis Regalia",
[823] = "Worldbreaker Battlegear",
[824] = "Worldbreaker Garb",
[825] = "Worldbreaker Regalia",
[826] = "Terrorblade Battlegear",
[827] = "Nightsong Battlegear",
[828] = "Nightsong Garb",
[829] = "Nightsong Regalia",
[830] = "Siegebreaker Battlegear",
[831] = "Siegebreaker Plate",
[832] = "Sanctification Garb",
[833] = "Sanctification Regalia",
[834] = "Darkruned Battlegear",
[835] = "Darkruned Plate",
[836] = "Kirin Tor Garb",
[837] = "Deathbringer Garb",
[838] = "Scourgestalker Battlegear",
[843] = "Khadgar's Regalia",
[844] = "Sunstrider's Regalia",
[845] = "Gul'dan's Regalia",
[846] = "Kel'Thuzad's Regalia",
[847] = "Velen's Raiment",
[848] = "Zabra's Raiment",
[849] = "Velen's Regalia",
[850] = "Zabra's Regalia",
[851] = "Malfurion's Garb",
[852] = "Runetotem's Garb",
[853] = "Malfurion's Regalia",
[854] = "Runetotem's Regalia",
[855] = "Malfurion's Battlegear",
[856] = "Runetotem's Battlegear",
[857] = "VanCleef's Battlegear",
[858] = "Garona's Battlegear",
[859] = "Windrunner's Battlegear",
[860] = "Windrunner's Pursuit",
[861] = "Nobundo's Garb",
[862] = "Thrall's Garb",
[863] = "Thrall's Regalia",
[864] = "Nobundo's Regalia",
[865] = "Nobundo's Battlegear",
[866] = "Thrall's Battlegear",
[867] = "Wrynn's Battlegear",
[868] = "Hellscream's Battlegear",
[869] = "Wrynn's Plate",
[870] = "Hellscream's Plate",
[871] = "Thassarian's Battlegear",
[872] = "Koltira's Battlegear",
[873] = "Thassarian's Plate",
[874] = "Koltira's Plate",
[875] = "Turalyon's Garb",
[876] = "Liadrin's Garb",
[877] = "Turalyon's Battlegear",
[878] = "Liadrin's Battlegear",
[879] = "Turalyon's Plate",
[880] = "Liadrin's Plate",
[881] = "Purified Shard of the Gods",
[882] = "Shiny Shard of the Gods",
[883] = "Bloodmage's Regalia",
[884] = "Dark Coven's Regalia",
[885] = "Crimson Acolyte's Raiment",
[886] = "Crimson Acolyte's Regalia",
[887] = "Lasherweave Garb",
[888] = "Lasherweave Regalia",
[889] = "Lasherweave Battlegear",
[890] = "Shadowblade's Battlegear",
[891] = "Ahn'Kahar Blood Hunter's Battlegear",
[892] = "Frost Witch's Garb",
[893] = "Frost Witch's Regalia",
[894] = "Frost Witch's Battlegear",
[895] = "Ymirjar Lord's Battlegear",
[896] = "Ymirjar Lord's Plate",
[897] = "Scourgelord's Battlegear",
[898] = "Scourgelord's Plate";
```

Example SQL of what it should do (single querys no loop)

SS showing filter of all items with item_template.itemset = 1, these are used in the query below for the item_loot_template [image: Filter Query For itemset = 1]

```
SET @setname = 'The Gladiator';
SET @ENTRYID = 500000;
SET @BASEENTRY = 500000;

INSERT INTO `item_template` (`entry`, `class`, `subclass`, `SoundOverrideSubclass`, `name`, `displayid`, `Quality`, `Flags`, `FlagsExtra`, `BuyCount`, `BuyPrice`, `SellPrice`, `InventoryType`, `AllowableClass`, `AllowableRace`, `ItemLevel`, `RequiredLevel`, `RequiredSkill`, `RequiredSkillRank`, `requiredspell`, `requiredhonorrank`, `RequiredCityRank`, `RequiredReputationFaction`, `RequiredReputationRank`, `maxcount`, `stackable`, `ContainerSlots`, `StatsCount`, `stat_type1`, `stat_value1`, `stat_type2`, `stat_value2`, `stat_type3`, `stat_value3`, `stat_type4`, `stat_value4`, `stat_type5`, `stat_value5`, `stat_type6`, `stat_value6`, `stat_type7`, `stat_value7`, `stat_type8`, `stat_value8`, `stat_type9`, `stat_value9`, `stat_type10`, `stat_value10`, `ScalingStatDistribution`, `ScalingStatValue`, `dmg_min1`, `dmg_max1`, `dmg_type1`, `dmg_min2`, `dmg_max2`, `dmg_type2`, `armor`, `holy_res`, `fire_res`, `nature_res`, `frost_res`, `shadow_res`, `arcane_res`, `delay`, `ammo_type`, `RangedModRange`, `spellid_1`, `spelltrigger_1`, `spellcharges_1`, `spellppmRate_1`, `spellcooldown_1`, `spellcategory_1`, `spellcategorycooldown_1`, `spellid_2`, `spelltrigger_2`, `spellcharges_2`, `spellppmRate_2`, `spellcooldown_2`, `spellcategory_2`, `spellcategorycooldown_2`, `spellid_3`, `spelltrigger_3`, `spellcharges_3`, `spellppmRate_3`, `spellcooldown_3`, `spellcategory_3`, `spellcategorycooldown_3`, `spellid_4`, `spelltrigger_4`, `spellcharges_4`, `spellppmRate_4`, `spellcooldown_4`, `spellcategory_4`, `spellcategorycooldown_4`, `spellid_5`, `spelltrigger_5`, `spellcharges_5`, `spellppmRate_5`, `spellcooldown_5`, `spellcategory_5`, `spellcategorycooldown_5`, `bonding`, `description`, `PageText`, `LanguageID`, `PageMaterial`, `startquest`, `lockid`, `Material`, `sheath`, `RandomProperty`, `RandomSuffix`, `block`, `itemset`, `MaxDurability`, `area`, `Map`, `BagFamily`, `TotemCategory`, `socketColor_1`, `socketContent_1`, `socketColor_2`, `socketContent_2`, `socketColor_3`, `socketContent_3`, `socketBonus`, `GemProperties`, `RequiredDisenchantSkill`, `ArmorDamageModifier`, `duration`, `ItemLimitCategory`, `HolidayId`, `ScriptName`, `DisenchantID`, `FoodType`, `minMoneyLoot`, `maxMoneyLoot`, `flagsCustom`, `VerifiedBuild`) VALUES 
(@ENTRYID, 15, 0, -1, 'name', 9632, 6, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 'discription', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12340);

update item_template SET name = concat(@setname, ' Set') WHERE item_template.entry = @ENTRYID;
update item_template SET item_template.description = concat('Contains the ', @setname) WHERE item_template.entry = @ENTRYID;
update item_template SET item_template.description = concat(item_template.description, ' Set') WHERE item_template.entry = @ENTRYID;

INSERT INTO `item_loot_template` (`Entry`, `Item`, `Reference`, `Chance`, `QuestRequired`, `LootMode`, `GroupId`, `MinCount`, `MaxCount`, `Comment`) VALUES 
(@BASEENTRY, 11726, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL),
(@BASEENTRY, 11728, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL),
(@BASEENTRY, 11729, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL),
(@BASEENTRY, 11730, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL),
(@BASEENTRY, 11731, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
```

End results of example query:

[image: End Result 1]
[image: End Result 2]

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Perhaps MySQL?)

Comment: take a look a cursors works kind of like a "loop"

Comment: Ideally, in SQL you don't write *loops*. You construct queries that takes *sets* of values from (potentially) multiple tables, joining the sets together as appropriate. You tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*, and you certainly don't break it down into "first, select *one* value from this table, then go and find matching rows in another table, ..."